# Serializing a game in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, load, save, game-engine

Im trying to serialize a snake game in Java, in which the game has to have the option to "**save**" and "**load**". Im not getting any error but whenever I try to print out the **lifes**, **time**, etc. It just gives me **0** when the **lifes** and time are not supposed to be **0**.

Heres is some of my code for the saving and loading part:

```
  public void SaveGame() throws IOException {

    PnlCentro pnlCentro = new PnlCentro();

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(pnlCentro);
    out.close();
}

public void LoadGame() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    PnlCentro p = null;

    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

    p = (PnlCentro) in.readObject();

    System.out.println("Body: " + p.vecBody);
    System.out.println("Life: " + p.life);
    System.out.println("Timer: " + p.getTime());

    in.close();
    fileIn.close();

}
```

Comment: You are saving `PnlCentro pnlCentro = new PnlCentro();` - a *new* instance - are you sure the *default* values (0 for numbers) are being changed?

Comment: Does `new PnlCentro()` set the  `vecBody`, `life` to values !=0 ?

Comment: I think when I add a new instance its changing all of the values to the original ones, but i dont know how to save it with the new ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your `SaveGame()` and `LoadGame` methods work perfectly, they just don't save or load any data from the current game session.

```
  public void SaveGame() throws IOException {

    PnlCentro pnlCentro = new PnlCentro(); //<-- Problem likely lies here!

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(pnlCentro);
    out.close();
}
```

Notice the initialization line for `pnlCentro` in the `SaveGame()` method. The object is declared and instantiated with the default constructor. Unless you have overrode the default constructor to instantiate the`pnlCentro` object with the current game data, then the current game data is never set prior to being written out to disk.

**Consider this:**

```
  public void SaveGame() throws IOException {

    PnlCentro pnlCentro = new PnlCentro();

    /* Set data prior to writing out */
    pnlCentro.setLives(getThisGamesNumLives());
    pnlCentro.setTime(getThisGamesTime());

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
    out.writeObject(pnlCentro);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Actually it did help somewhat, the problem was that I needed to create a new instance of the class, because I was working in a separate class for the save and load methods, but whenever I create a instance of the class all my variables reset. So I just made the save and load methods inside the class im serializing.

Comment: @BryamUlloa So it sounds like my answer was ***acceptable?*** *cough-cough-hint-hint*

Answer (score 2):

In the SaveGame method, you always create a new instance of PnlCentro before serializing, when you use the code:

```
PnlCentro pnlCentro = new PnlCentro();
```

There is no modification to the default values of the object plnCentro before the serialization and maybe that's why you are reading zeros after deserialization.